# Unable to perform git commit

Tags: node.js, git

I am getting the following issue when I am try to commit my files
"node" is not recognized as external or internal command
I have the path for both git and node in environment variable

[image]

Comment: That sounds like you might have a misconfigured pre-commit hook. Try with `--no-verify`, and if that works, look in your `.git/hooks` directory.

Comment: Try typing `node` from your command line to make sure it can actually see it. (Note if you just added it to your path you may have to close and reopen your command window.)

Comment: Try to avoid using images in questions. See [ask]

Comment: Have you tried putting a space between the -m and ":
$> git commit -m "merge"

If not, then try the suggestion about the pre-commit hooks as given by @AKX

Comment: Doing a husky install may help you.  `npx husky install`